# clang-format-3.4 unwanted space between closing bracket and colon in switch case(C-pgm)

Tags: c, clang-format

Sir..

```
switch (skb->protocol) {
case cpu_to_be16(ETH_P_IP):
```

this is my code, `cpu_to_be16(ETH_P_IP)` is the macro name.

after passing it to `clang-format-3.4`
i got

```
switch (skb->protocol) {
case cpu_to_be16(ETH_P_IP) :
```

here i dont want space before colon(in between closing bracket and colon). according to linux coding style it is error. i tried with almost all different configuration(`.clang-format` file), but it introduces space. how to fix it?

Comment: when you compile the code (all warnings enabled) do you get an error or warning message about the space?   I doubt it.  A coding style is just that, a style (a style is used for readability) and should make absolutely not difference to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Sir..
There is no compilation error..

According to linux kernel coding style(www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) there should not be space before colon in case statement. When I passed code through linux/checkpatch.pl there will be error(ERROR: space prohibited before that ':'). No problem with copilation.

Solved: In clang-format-3.6 problem gets solved. it has not introduced space before colon. Thank you.